# InitialContext lookup very slow in Glassfish server

Tags: java, jndi, glassfish-4

I have a default Glassfish server setup and I'm trying to lookup the default connection factory for JMS (`jms/__defaultConnectionFactory`). I can get the `InitialContext` but when I call `lookup` it 'hangs' for about 60 secs (sometimes more sometimes less) before finally returning the correct value (so it does work but takes forever).

The code is fairly simple:

```
initialContext = new InitialContext();
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) 
                              initialContext.lookup(connectionFactoryName);
```

I've also tried setting the ORBInitialHost and ORBInitialPort properties before creating the initial context:

```
System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
```

before calling lookup (I've also added these to the jndi.properties file).

It's not the lookup of the default connection factory that is the issue, it's the first time I call lookup against the server, subsequent lookups happen quickly

Any ideas as to how to fix this would be welcome